# How do I remove newline in yaml

Tags: bash, awk, sed, git-bash

I have a yaml-file like this:

```
yaml: >-
    random
another: normaltext
```

With the help of bash I would like to get this output:

```
yaml: random
another: normaltext
```

This text is different every time.

I've tried `tr -d '>-'` but then the newline is still there. And if i try `tr -d '\n'` then the whole structure falls apart.

Comment: Do you have access to `awk` or `sed`? Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -Ezi 's/>-[[:space:]]+//g' yamlfile
```

Consume the file as one line (-z) and then substitute regular expression space, >- , one or more spaces for nothing.

Comment: `-z` is a lot easier than using those obscure pattern operators. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I would explicitly match `\n`. Note that `blabla: "some >-     value"` will also be modified. Like `>-[[:blank:]]*\n[[:blank:]]+`

Answer (score 1):

Some sample data with additional (nonsensical) content:

```
$ cat yaml.file
yaml: >-
    random
another: normaltext
leave this line ... as is
something else >-
  more stuff on this line
and leave this line alone, too
```

One `awk` solution:

```
$ awk '
/>-/ { sub(">-","")            # if line contains the string ">-" then remove it
       l1=$0                   # save current/modified line in variable "l1"
       getline                 # get next line
       $1=$1                   # strip off leading spaces
       print l1 $0             # print our 2 lines
       next                    # skip to next line
      }
1                              # always true => print the current line
' yaml.file
```

As a one-liner sans comments:

```
$ awk '/>-/ {sub(">-",""); l1=$0; getline; $1=$1; print l1 $0; next}1' yaml.file
```

The above generates the following output:

```
yaml: random
another: normaltext
leave this line ... as is
something else more stuff on this line
and leave this line alone, too
```